# How to set up a multi-project SBT project with inheritance and shared dependencies

Tags: sbt

I'd like to create an SBT project with inheritance and shared dependencies.

With Maven's POM files, there is the idea of [Project Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) where you can set a `parent` project. I'd like to do the same thing with SBT.

The [`xchange-stream` library](https://github.com/bitrich-info/xchange-stream) uses Maven's Project Inheritance to resolve subproject dependencies when compiled from the parent project.

Here is my idea of what the file structure would look like:

```
sbt-project/
  project/
    dependencies.scala    # Contains dependencies common to all projects
  build.sbt               # Contains definition of parent project with references
                          # to subprojects

  subproject1/
    build.sbt             # Contains `subproject3` as a dependency

  subproject2/
    build.sbt             # Contains `subproject3` as a dependency

  subproject3/
    build.sbt             # Is a dependency for `subproject1` and `subproject2`
```

Where `project1` and `project2` can include `project3` in their dependencies lists like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= "tld.organization" % "project3" % "1.0.0"
```

Such that when `subproject1` or `subproject2` are compiled by invoking `sbt compile` from within their subdirectories, or when the parent: `sbt-project` is compiled from the main `sbt-project` directory, then `subproject3` will be compiled and published locally with SBT, or otherwise be made available to the projects that need it.

Also, how would shared dependencies be specified in `sbt-project/build.sbt` or anywhere in the `sbt-project/project` directory, such that they are useable within `subproject1` and `subproject2`, when invoking `sbt compile` within those subdirectories?

The following examples don't help answer either of the above points:

1. [`jbruggem/sbt-multiproject-example`](https://github.com/jbruggem/sbt-multiproject-example):
   Uses recursive `build.sbt` files, but doesn't share dependencies among child projects.
2. [Defining Multi-project Builds with sbt](https://pbassiner.github.io/blog/defining_multi-project_builds_with_sbt.html): [`pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example`](https://github.com/pbassiner/sbt-multi-project-example):
   Uses a single `build.sbt` file for the projects in their subdirectories.
3. [`sachabarber/SBT_MultiProject_Demo`](https://github.com/sachabarber/SBT_MultiProject_Demo):
   Uses a single `build.sbt` file.

Answer (score 3):

> Such that when `subproject1` or `subproject2` are compiled by invoking `sbt compile` from within their subdirectories...

Maybe Maven is meant to be used together with the shell environment and `cd` command, but that's not how sbt works at least as of sbt 1.x in 2019.

The sbt way is to use `sbt` as an interactive shell, and start it at the top level. You can then either invoke compilation as `subproject1/compile`, or switch into it using `project subproject1`, and call `compile` in there.

#### house plugin

A feature similar to parent POM would be achieved by creating a custom plugin.

```scala
package com.example

import sbt._
import Keys._

object FooProjectPlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin

  val commonsIo = "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "2.6"

  override def buildSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    organization := "com.example"
  )
  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    libraryDependencies += commonsIo
  )
}
```

#### sbt-sriracha

It's not exactly what you are asking for, but I have an experimental plugin that allows you to switch between source dependency and binary dependency. See [hot source dependencies using sbt-sriracha](http://eed3si9n.com/hot-source-dependencies-using-sbt-sriracha).

Using that you could create three individual sbt builds for `project1`, `project2`, and `project3`, all located inside `$HOME/workspace` directory.

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.1-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val project3Ref = ProjectRef(workspaceDirectory / "project3", "project3")
lazy val project3Lib = "tld.organization" %% "project3" % "0.1.0"

lazy val project1 = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(FooProjectPlugin)
  .sourceDependency(project3Ref, project3Lib)
  .settings(
    name := "project1"
  )
```

With this setup, you can launch `sbt -Dsbt.sourcemode=true` and it will pick up project3 as a subproject.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mecha super-repo concept. Take a look on the setup and docs here: https://github.com/storm-enroute/mecha

The basic idea is that you can combine dependent sbt projects (with their own build.sbt) under single root super-repo sbt project:

```
/root
  /project/plugins.sbt
  repos.conf

  /project1
    /src/..
    /project/plugins.sbt
    build.sbt

  /project2
    /src/..
    /project/plugins.sbt
    build.sbt
```

Please, note that there is no `build.sbt` in the root folder!
Instead there is `repos.conf` file. It contains definition of the sub-repos and looks like the folowing:

```
  root {
    dir = "."
    origin = ""
    mirrors = []
  }

  project1 {
    dir = "project1"
    origin = "git@github.com:some_user/project1.git"
    mirrors = []
  }

  project2 {
    dir = "project2"
    origin = "git@github.com:some_user/project2.git"
    mirrors = []
  }
```

Then you can specify the **Inter-Project, source-level Dependencies** within individual projects.

There are two approaches:

- `dependencies.conf` file
- or in the build source code

For more details, please, see the [docs](https://github.com/storm-enroute/mecha)